# How to get token from XHR element

Tags: python

Looking for help with getting a token without having to manually grab it through the browser. I have written some code to go through the json request URL but i always have to manually get the token before each session. Wondering if there's a way to grab it automatically through python. Thank you.

i.e. the element "getEnhancedQuotes.json?symbols=RY" under XHR from the page https://web.tmxmoney.com/financials.php?qm_symbol=ry

The request URL for the json will look like the following with the token being different each time - https://app.quotemedia.com/datatool/getEnhancedQuotes.json?symbols=RY&timezone=true&afterhours=true&premarket=true&currencyInd=true&countryInd=true&marketstatus=true&reportType=A&token=aa712710d436e041df90e5e4a876827c3e066e156bc5da38efbc3ffa683e5439

Comment: This seems rather broad, is there no information already available on this subject? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I searched for awhile before posting the question but couldn't find anything.